# Multiple realms

Tags: java, hadoop, kerberos

I am setting up a client and connecting to multiple Kerberos enabled systems using a java client.

Using `UserGroupInformation`. Java client always picks the `default_realm` and throws error if am using other realms.

Is it possible to connect using different keytabs and different principals but use the same `krb5.conf`?

`/etc/krb5.conf`:

```
[libdefaults]
default_realm = NEW.COM
dns_lookup_realm = false
dns_lookup_kdc = false
ticket_lifetime = 1d
renew_lifetime = 7d
forwardable = true

[realms]
NEW.COM = {
  kdc = bharath.kdc
  admin_server = bharath.kdc
}

EXAMPLE.COM = {
  kdc = wckdserver.krbnet
  admin_server = wckdserver.krbnet
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can control which keytab is used with a jaas config file of the form:

```
client {
  com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule required
  refreshKrb5Config=true
  useKeyTab=true
  keyTab="<path to keytab>"
  principal="<user>@<realm>";
};
```

This config file is set with the system property:

```
-Djava.security.auth.login.config=<path to jaas config>
```

If you want to change the settings during a single run of the VM you will need to clear the cached user configuration in the VM with:

```
Configuration.setConfiguration(null);
```

To use different realms you need to specify **both** of the following properties:

```
-Djava.security.krb5.realm=<realm>
-Djava.security.krb5.kdc=<kdc>
```

Comment: I am using the following API to login.
UserGroupInformation.setConfiguration(configuration);        UserGroupInformation.loginUserFromKeytab("principal","/root/new.keytab");

And if set following setProperty then i cant use the same client  to use different realms.
-Djava.security.krb5.realm=<realm>
-Djava.security.krb5.kdc=<kdc>

Comment: So firstly, this is hadoop related which isn't in the tags. Secondly, in what context are you doing this? In and MR job? Do you have hadoop configured for kerberos?

Comment: This hadoop with webhdfs and kerberos enabled. I am able Knint using different keytabs and different realms.But java code mentioned above isn't working.Java apis always takes the default_realms mentioned in krb5.conf as default and doesn't recognize other realms....

Answer (score 1):

You can have two (or more) sections in a JAAS config file for different keytab files, like this:

```
com.sun.security.jgss.krb5.accept {

 com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule required
 principal="user1@DOMAIN1.COM" useKeyTab=true
 keyTab="C:\\Oracle\\Middleware12.1.1\\MyDomain\\domain1_keytab" storeKey=true;

 com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule required
 principal="user2@DOMAIN2.COM" useKeyTab=true
 keyTab="C:\\Oracle\\Middleware12.1.1\\MyDomain\\domain2_keytab" storeKey=true;

};
```

You may need to remove all realm info from your config files. Then when you change this system setting:

```
System.setProperty("sun.security.krb5.principal", "userX@DOMAINX.COM");
```

where "X" should be replaced by 1 or 2, you can make Kerberos to pick a different keytab file.

System will search for relevant section in JAAS config based on "sun.security.krb5.principal" setting and will use this principal and its corresponding keytab for Kerberos authentication.

Answer (score 0):

To configure multiple realms set your `krb5.conf` like so:

```
[libdefaults]
default_realm = XYZ.LOCAL

[realms]
XYZ.LOCAL = {
  kdc = abc.xyz.local
  default_domain = XYZ.LOCAL
}

SECOND.NET = {
  kdc = abc.second.net
}

[domain_realm]
.xyz.local = .XYZ.LOCAL
xyz.local = XYZ.LOCAL
.second.net = .SECOND.NET
second.net = SECOND.NET
```

Answer (score 0):

My use case was slightly different, but sharing because it sounds sufficiently similar so this might work for you.

Add to krb5.conf:

```
[domain_realm]
  .example.com = EXAMPLE.COM
```

Then when you connect to *.example.com, it will use the EXAMPLE.COM realm instead of the default.

More here: https://web.mit.edu/kerberos/krb5-1.12/doc/admin/conf_files/krb5_conf.html#domain-realm